# How to boot a debootstrap-ed system bare metal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, boot, initrd

I `debootstrap` an Ubuntu Xenial system as:

```
debootstrap --variant=minbase --include=linux-image-generic,linux-headers-generic,systemd,systemd-sysv,dbus --components=main,restricted,universe,multiverse xenial ubuntu_dir http://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu
```

I extract the kernel as:

```
cd ubuntu_dir && cp boot/vmlinu* ../xenial.kernel
```

I create the initrd as:

```
cd ubuntu_dir && find . -print0 | cpio --quiet --null -ov --format=newc | gzip -9 > ../xenial.initrd
```

I boot the system in `qemu` as (it boots over PXE):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -kernel xenial.kernel -initrd xenial.initrd -m 4096M -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

The kernel panics saying:

```
kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)
```

[image]

I need to boot this kernel+initrd pair over PXE. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you providing a root file system?

Comment: I want the system to boot live (in memory, downloaded over PXE). So essentially I want the `initrd` image to be mounted as the root file system; changes made will not be persistent. How can I do that?